# 451 Queuing declined or disabled; try again later

Tags: email, postfix

I've setup postfix+mysql+dovecot mail server, and it's working correctly, mails are going out except when I try to send to test@allaboutspam.com
I get a
`Nov 18 13:32:56 server postfix/smtp[5662]: 8E3773008C3: to=<test@allaboutspam.com>, relay=mx.allaboutspam.com[96.126.107.60]:25, delay=353395, delays=353394/0.03/0.32/0.4, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx.allaboutspam.com[96.126.107.60] said: 451 Queuing declined or disabled; try again later (in reply to end of DATA command))`
They should receive the message then bounce it back with some data, but they don't receive it in the first place.
Have been googling for ages now. Please help.

Comment: The far end might just be greylisting you.  Let postfix retry a few times and see if the message gets delivered.

Comment: There isn't much of anything _you_ can do about problems at the _other end_ except report it to them. We are not them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing send an email to [Unlock The Inbox Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) - Does the same thing but with a lot more information. Their mail server might be having issues or is Greylisting you. Any mail testing system shouldn't Greylist you without a way to remove yourself. It kind of defeats the purpose of them.